# How to implement OCR(Optical Character Recognition) within Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

With my work, I was assigned to build a OCR reader for a Salesforce custom object. I do not want to use any AppExchange products, so wanted to implement entire functionality myself using Lightning components/Apex controllers.

Can someone shed some insights on how/where to start with the development? I am not looking for any code samples, rather wanted to know how I can implement it myself with the current Salesforce resources/any APIs needed/REST/SOAP. Just looking for the implementing procedure to do so. Any thoughts/leads would be much appreciated.

Comment: You absolutely cannot do it server side on platform. Has to be front end only. Because of that, no API would be possible nor any sort of scheduled/async job. You're going to have to [research JS OCR](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+ocr&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab) and start experimenting.

Comment: Salesforce Einstien vision may be?